# Question about inverse of element in a group

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let G be a set with an operation *

If c is the inverse element of b in G, in order to have (G,*) as a group, is it necessary that b should be the inverse element of c, or can it have another inverse in G?

Comment: Since $c$ is the inverse of $b$, we get $bc=cb=1$. What is the inverse of $c$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $a=b^{-1}$, in a group,  then $a^{-1}=(b^{-1})^{-1}=b^{-1\cdot-1}=b$.

Alternatively,  inverses are unique.   For if $b,c=a^{-1}$, then $b=b\cdot e=b(ac)=(ba)c=e\cdot c=c$.

Answer (score 0):

When you say that $G$ is a set with operation $*$ this is not enough information to say $c$ is the inverse of $b$ as we do not necessarily have an identity. Without one, we can't state that $bc=cb=1$, so it doesn't mean anything to say that $bc=cb=1$.

If the operation $*$ on $G$ admits an identity $1$ then we can ask your question. In general, the answer is then no, inverses are not unique. If you also specify that $*$ is associative, then the answer will be yes, as shown in the other answer.